# Calling SKSpriteNodes based on of their name

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In my SpriteKit Game i have several sprites with different name properties .

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"png"];
        sprite.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name%i",i];
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
```

Is it possible to call one of these sprites based on their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what i was looking for.. use

```
[self childNodeWithName:@"name"];
```

to search for a specific node.